# what is the difference between JMenuItem and JMenu

Tags: java, jmenu

What is the difference between **JMenuItem** and **JMenu**?

```
JMenu m;
JMenuItem i;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`JMenu`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html) is the menu itself, or as the documentation states:

> An implementation of a menu -- a popup window containing `JMenuItem`s that is displayed when the user selects an item on the `JMenuBar`.

A [`JMenuItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html) is a single item in such a menu. Or, as the documentation describes it:

> An implementation of an item in a menu. A menu item is essentially a button sitting in a list. When the user selects the "button", the action associated with the menu item is performed.

Answer (score -1):

JMenu extends JMenuItem.
The different is that JMenu is an *item* which can contain other JMenuItems. Think of it as being a SubMenu.

Comment: "...as being a SubMenu..."; actually it's "...has sub-menu(s)".

Comment: @geowar The JMenuBar is a menu which can recusivly contain JMenus. By that definition, all JMenus are submenus of the JMenuBar. Why the downvote?

Comment: Because JMenu being a sub-menu doesn't distinguish it from JMenuItems; they can both be sub-menus. OTOH JMenuItems can not have sub-menus where as JMenus can. That's the difference; can have sub-menus, not being a sub-menu.